# Unity - having problem with emission, how to use emission in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, post-processing

I am trying to implement emission to my particle. But it just doesn't seem to work whatever I do. I've looked up on the internet to find a solution but nothing has solved the problem for me so far. Is there something that I seem to miss? [image: material] [image: scene footage]

Comment: not having a texture like yours to hand, i made a material which was emissive, it showed red glow in the material box at the bottom and tada, i had red emissive particles.. so, question then becomes, what exactly did you do, is your emission a high enough number?

Comment: it doesn't change anything even when i increase or decrease the intensity, nothing changes in the particle

Comment: Not sure if it'll work but you could try setting the emissive texture to a plain white texture (instead of the same texture as your base map) since it should only apply to visible pixels regardless, if that doesn't work try setting your base texture to a plain white one too to see if its a texture related issue

Comment: Followup question: what shader are you using for the material?

Comment: urp particles lit